# How to summon minecraft zombie with armor in 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have no idea how to summon mobs or zombies more specifically with armor and swords. I use the command `/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:267}]}` for an iron sword or replacing the id with Minecraft:iron_sword which comes to an expectable command but it just spawns the zombie with nothing. Any one know the right command?

Answer (score 1):

‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​Found the answer almost immediately. The command for this with an iron sword and leather cap is `/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{Count:1,id:iron_sword},{}],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{Count:1,id:leather_helmet}]}`.